# Chrome rendering bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have come across a weird kind of inconsistence in rendering in Chrome.

A simplified example of the issue can be replicated by using the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    input, span {
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        padding: 3px 4px;
        height: 23px;
        width: 120px;
        display: block;
        font-size: 13px;
    }  
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><span>123</span></div>
    <div><input type='text'/></div>
</body>
</html>​
```

So, in a few words, the `span` and `input` should have the same size, but it turns out, that Chrome renders the elements differently:

- Span is rendered so it's actual size is `31px`
- Input is rendered so it's actual size is `23px`

Upon investigation it looks like Chrome renders the `span` so it's "inner" (without border and padding) size is 20 px, while `input` is rendered so it's "outer" size is 20px.

In real application the controls are used in a "in-place edit" scenario, so when user clicks the span, the span becomes hidden and input is shown on it's place. As you can see, with such a difference in size, the transition isn't smooth. Wjat's worth is that the controls are placed in a table cell, so the difference in width and height cause the whole table to change layout a bit.

I'm working on a cross-platform application, so it should work in IE9 as well. The problem is that IE renders both `input` and `span` of the same size, so the page looks quite different in IE and Chrome. To make the my life harder, those controls are rendered by ASP.NET server controls, and I'm allowed to change css only.

I'm using Chrome 23.0.1271.91 (latest at the moment of posting) on Win7x64.

So, thre are two questions actually:

1. How do I fix this?
2. Why it's happening? Am I missing something obvious? Is it an expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome sets `box-sizing: border-box;` by default on input elements and textareas.

Set `box-sizing: content-box` to make them both behave like the span or both to border-box to make them behave like the input.

A good explanation about the box-sizing methods can be found here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves the problem. Also, the link is quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since Chrome supports box-sizing, try:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    input, span {
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        padding: 3px 4px;
        height: 23px;
        width: 120px;
        display: block;
        box-sizing:border-box;

    }  
    </style>    
</head>
<body>
    <div><span>123</span></div>
    <div><input type='text'/></div>
</body>
</html>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9esTQ/

Comment: The answer is helpful, but if you run jsfiddle without box-sizing it shows the same result. That's why I've used pastebin :)